# How do I update a table once I change a year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, html-table

I am building a table dynamically on the page, and I need to be able to update the information, and also provide a link to the updated information.

Currently, if I try wrapping a function around the code that has been run once, I get an error on the inner function that the open parenthesis is unexpected (the function under update table).

The way it works, the initial rows are populated with the results from the buildCal function, to my knowledge, since it is using .innerHTML it should be no issue in replacing that data in the table, by just running that function again. If I could understand why the inner function will not run again in the displayDate function that would help a lot. I considered it may have been because this is all in the success function instead of adding the rebuilding to the complete function, but I didn't know how to call that if I couldn't even add the outer function to the main (success) code block.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Events";

      var listname = "Events";

      var events = [];

      $.ajax({
        url: url, //THE ENDPOINT
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success:
        //want to use this function as a named function to re-call everything       
          function updateTable(data) {
          //this is the main function which builds everything       
          function(data) {

          })

      });
```

```html
<div id="calNavPanel">

  <a id="prevYearGo">
    <<&nbsp;</a>
      <div id="currentYear"></div><a id="nextYearGo">&nbsp;>></a>

</div>
<table id="calendar">
  <tr>
    <td id="cal" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal1" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal2" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal3" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal4" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal5" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal6" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal7" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal8" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal9" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal10" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal11" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cal12" class="calendarDateSectionClass"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: make it short if you can

Comment: For future reference, please try only to include relevant code. You might have had an answer already but people have probably skipped over your question.

Comment: I have a really hard time identifying what is not useful, ugh, and now I can't ask again. No one ever comes bac.

Comment: @Andrew the vast majority of my questions either get the comment that it is too much or not enough.

Comment: Hey, it's alright. They will probably come back, don't worry. In fact, I'll bookmark your question and check back later.

Comment: Please add your code to a snippet and tidy it. Makes it much more readable as you can see now I did it for you. You will then also see you have non-matching brackets (you should not have two functions inside each other in the success) Also why text/ecmascript instead of text/javascript or nothing?

Comment: You do not only want to change the success part of the ajax to a named function, you want to change the code starting with `var listname` into a function. Where is the variable year in the endpoint `url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Events";` ?